# How to write the xml for a mesh with texture for standalone Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I am not able to figure out what to write to make standalone cycles use a UV map. I have written a shader like this for a mesh

```
<shader name="shader27">
    <texture_coordinate name="texcod"/>
    <mapping name="map" translation="0.0, 0.0, 0.0" rotation="0, 0, 0" scale="1, 1, 1"/>
    <image_texture name="imgtex" filename="path to Image"/>
    <diffuse_bsdf name="diffuse"/>
    <connect from="texcod Generated" to="map Vector"/>
    <connect from="map Vector" to="imgtex Vector"/>
    <connect from="imgtex Color" to="diffuse Color"/>
    <connect from="diffuse BSDF" to="output surface"/>
</shader>
```

The mesh node looks like this:

```
<transform rotate="90.00000000000001 0 -1 0" translate="-0.0025990686416625976 0 1.1102230246251566e-18" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001">
    <state interpolation="smooth" shader="shader27">
        <mesh P="-1.9988649877621822 -1.675 0 1.9988649877621822 -1.675 0 1.9988649877621822 1.675 0 -1.9988649877621822 1.675 0" nverts="3 3 " verts="0 1 2 0 2 3" UV="-1.9988649877621822 -1.675 1.9988649877621822 -1.675 1.9988649877621822 1.675 -1.9988649877621822 1.675"/>
    </state>
</transform>
```

Even though the texture appears, it does not use the uv map. Can anyone working with cycles guide me on this?